# Is there a function for removing trailing spaces in a buffer?

Tags: whitespace

Does emacs have a built in function for removing trailing spaces in a buffer?  I want to remove trailing whitespace at the end of all the lines in a buffer.

Comment: Removing them from what?  strings?  buffer text?  Where have you searched for an answer before coming here?

Comment: Please clarify if you are looking for a function that deletes trailing whitespace from a buffer (as @Ryan's answer addresses), or if you're looking to remove whitespace from a string, or something else.

Comment: delete-horizontal-space ?

Comment: I am new to emacs and not sure of the appropriate terminology, but from the questions here I believe it must mean trailing spaces in a buffer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!  We've reopened the question, although it looks like you've got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace#toc3), `M-x delete-trailing-whitespace` will eliminate all trailing whitespace in a buffer. In Spacemacs, it is bound to `SPC x d w` by default

You can do it automatically for all buffers by adding the following to your `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

For future reference, you can search for Emacs functions within Emacs by typing `M-x apropos`, then typing your query. In this case, `M-x apropos <RET> whitespace <RET>` provides a list of functions relating to whitespace.

Comment: apropos is a nice tip thank you

Comment: what if I want to avoid this in modes where it has special meaning like in markdown, but apply it in all other modes?